# What is the best Saga Redux pattern to get http response?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, saga

I'm looking for the best approach to get the response from a sagas request for a particular case. I'm not sure if this is really the case to use Sagas. The thing is that since I'm using sagas in my project, I'm trying to make every call to the backend using sagas. Therefore, my components never actually make the request, they just dispatch the requests to sagas.

**Here's what I need to do:**

I have to send a request to my backend, it will do some validation and return a message. I need to get this message and display to the user

**Here's what I would do:**

- I would create an action 'sendSomethingRequest', then in my reducer this action will set 'isLoading: true'. This action will be dispatched by my component.
- I would then create a generator function that will take this action, make the request to the back end, return, and then I would create another action 'sendSomethingSuccess'. This new action will put the message in redux state. My component then is listening to redux's state and I can just get the info.

Is there any better way to doing this?

Not sure if storing this kind of info in redux makes much sense.

Comment: Generally, if you use sagas you will have to lift some UI state (like the loading/message) to redux store. That is the price of using sagas. It is also possible to put some callback function into the success action and sent the result to the component though it, but i never liked that approach, because technically there could be multiple sagas handling the same action and then things get tricky.

Comment: Using the UI state seems reasonable to me, and it's what I am doing. The thing is that I had this idea that we only store global stuff in redux, so loading data that would be used by only one component didn't seem right.